# Yii and cron jobs

Tags: php, yii, cron

I have created a Yii command that needs to be run every month. If I go to my protected folder and run the command manually:

`protected/yiic ganadores`

It works fine. I have tried to add the following command line to `etc/cron.hourly` and `etc/crontab` with no success:

`/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/path/to/project/protected/yiic ganadores` (etc/cron.hourly/ganadores)

`0  0   1 * *  root   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/path/to/project/protected/yiic ganadores`
 (etc/crontab)

If I run the file `ganadores` inside `etc/cron.hourly` manually, it's working also.

What am I missing here?

**Edit:** Finally got it solved. I had some extra spaces in the cron line. Used tab instead spaces and it started working..

Comment: Can you say a little more about what happens?  Do you see anything in syslog at the time the cron should run? What OS are you on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I run my Yii cron jobs (in the root crontab file):

```
45 23 * * * sudo -u www-data php /path/to/yii/app/protected/console.php mycommand
```

Basically just regular crontab syntax, but I am running console.php instead of yiic, and I am setting the user to Apache (www-data) so the permissions are correct for my script. I am not sure why yours isn't working, but hopefully looking at mine will help you out. :)

Comment: Have tried with both, changing the user to Apache and running console.php instead of yiic. Still nothing :(

Comment: Check if yiic is executable [ sudo chmod +x yiic ]

Comment: if you use Linux CENTOS 5.5, you should add an empty line after last cron job!