# How to run Yii controller action In a particular time interval ?

Tags: yii

I want to run a Yii controller action in a particular time interval. So I used the Windows 7 task scheduler for performing this. But nothing happens. Is it possible to run the Yii controller action using ***Windows Task scheduler*** ?

If so what is the syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with crone jobs. Here are some links which will help you.

**[1.Implementing cron jobs with Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/91/implementing-cron-jobs-with-yii/)**
(*check the comments there too*)

**[2.Yii and cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235888/yii-and-cron-jobs)**

**[3.Console Applications](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console)**

**[4.Yii-Crontab - an extension(*Manages system cron jobs. Supports Application console commands*)](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-crontab/)**

**[5.Runactions](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/runactions/)**

Comment: I want to implement this on windows